# Replicating phone gap to a native ios and android app issue

Tags: android, json, swift, api, phonegap

We have a phone gap cross-platform built app and we are building the same app in native.

The app has pages/views with text with embedded hyperlinks in them where it sends the user to other pages in the same app. Of course because this is `HTML` based so this is possible using phone gap apps. But what if we changed that to native how can we have links inside a text where it redirects users to other views or grabs other data from the database and pushes them to the `UIViewController`?

How will the backend send us `JSON` strings with hyperlinks in them that will be able to replicate what the phone gap built app does. Is this possible?

Ok maybe we can send embedded `HTML` in the `JSON` data. But how will these `<a>` links open or grab other data from the server?

I find it very complicated or maybe not doable at all. Anybody has ideas on how this could be solved?

A screen shot of what i mean. This is a phone gap app.

[image: a screen shot example of the phone gap app]

Comment: So are these web links are like fetching data from your server and showing on the page?

Comment: Can you describe your app a little.. is it like shopping app which shows some links of products and after clicking it opens the details page or something

Comment: @xSHERU i added a screen shot to the question. This is a view. With text with blue links. These links direct you to other data like a website. But is possible with phone gap. How to do this same thing using native language and parsing json data from the server.

Comment: Your question is related to broad area. So i really can’t give you exact answer here but you can use webview to show the post and use android components for displaying the list of posts. If user clicks on post item you can open that post in the new page inside webview. That way your inline links also taken care of without lot of work.

Comment: It is definitely doable though.

Comment: @xSHERU the idea is that we don’t want it in a webview. We want it to be in the navigation itself.

Comment: @xSHERU the problem is that we don’t want it in a webview. We want it in the navigation of the app itself. Native.

Comment: For that you need to have a structured data of the posts. You need to create model of post like title, subtitle, content etc. and create a generalised view using android components and using App call to your server fetch and fill the data in it.

Comment: Inline links are little hard but you can create an api which accepts these words and show some results.

Comment: We can discuss further if you need. Join me in stack overflow chat.

Comment: @xSHERU yes dear of course i know all that. What about the links in the string content of the text. I have a string json from where will i get the links on certain words?

Comment: Can you give me an example of this inline link. Are these link to another post or just show posts related to the word?

Comment: @xSHERU these are ordinary website links. Plus the app owner wants these links to be directed to content inside the navigation of the app. For example these are questions of title and description. In the description there are links as you see that lead to other questions. And had to be inside the same app. This one is with phone gap so all is html. We use json.

Comment: There is a spannable string in android and attributed string in ios which you can use for clickable words in text and add some similar logic as the main posts and open the new activity and fetch data from server. Only thing will be creating that much structured data.

Comment: @xSHERU exactly thats my point i know attributed text but the json itself. This is my issue.

Answer (score 1):

All right first and foremost you need structured data.

Lets say I opend a main post with id '14'. Api will fetch data from server for id 14.

JSON structure can be like this:

```
{"title":"What are origional sin?","content":"Although Adam & Eve had been given. God has given man free will.","inlineLinks":[{"startIndex":"8","endIndex":"18","contentId":"141"},{"startIndex":"55","endIndex":"64","contentId":"142"}]}
```

Now using spannable string in android and attributed string in ios you now have id for specific inline link content and start and end index which you can use to add clicks to specific inline links. Once user clicks these link you have id of that specific content which you can open in your app.

Since you know the spannable string I hope you dont need the detail code.

Wish you have started your question with Spannable String problem.

Please ignore the indexes incase they are wrong ;)